# Why i get 403: Forbidden request with cypress

Tags: request, cypress

I am using vpn to access the website,and with other website that i dont need it, the test work fine, but for this website that i need vpn cypress get me the next answer.
I am workin with cypress and need vpn to access to this website

````
request
GET 403 https://private-5bdb3-friendmock.apiary-mock.com/friends
CypressError
cy.request() failed on:

https://private-5bdb3-friendmock.apiary-mock.com/friends

The response we received from your web server was:

  > 403: Forbidden

This was considered a failure because the status code was not 2xx or 3xx.

If you do not want status codes to cause failures pass the option: failOnStatusCode: false

-----------------------------------------------------------

The request we sent was:

Method: GET
URL: https://private-5bdb3-friendmock.apiary-mock.com/friends
Headers: {
  "Connection": "keep-alive",
  "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36",
  "accept": "/",
  "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate"
}```

Any helps, maybe i nedd a proxy, but i am not sure.
````

Comment: Did you check the response in Postman or a similar tool? Don't think this is a Cypress issue

Comment: @cypher_null yes i did and work perfect, i did with postman and alse in my app work fine, i just have to use vpn for it

Comment: I am sorry but I can not reproduce the problem. I sent a GET request to the url you posted in Cypress and it returns status 200

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the VPN, I need a VPN, so the problem is gone after that.